# Dynamically replace links in existing pdf file

Tags: pdf

Let's imagine i have an existing pdf file, created with Microsoft Word or InDesign for example.

This pdf file contains links.

Let's suppose this pdf file is used to be downloaded from a webserver.

What i want to do is to replace each link by another, on the fly for each download.

What i tried to do is to write a php script. The pdf is in a private directory on the web server. The php scripts opens it and flush its content to browser.

But i do not know how to change each links...

Thanks

Comment: Do you hope for a PHP solution? Then you should tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

- Each PDF page object, that has links, has an `/Annots` key. The value of this key is an array of (references to) annotation objects (see PDF 1.7 spec, section 7.7.3.3).
- If such an annotation object has a `/Subtype` key with value `/Link`, it is a link annotation (see PDF 1.7 spec, section 12.5.6.5).
- If such a link annotation has a key `/AA`, the value is a (reference to an) action object.
- If such an action object has a `/S` key with value `/URI`, it is an action to open a URI. The URI itself is available through the `/URI` key (see PDF 1.7 spec, section 12.6.4.7).

So to change the links, you need a PDF library that allows access to the PDF internal objects. Then you can just follow the instructions above.